# DaVinci Resolve playback freeze

Tags: 19.04, proprietary

After many attempts to install Resolve on Ubuntu, I finally got it. 
But here is the problem, file playback stops after a certain amount of time. Tried PNG, EXR sequences, but result every time the same. I press play one time with no lags, normal FPS, two.. and after that image just stops updating.

I noted, that it depends on source files. Video files can plays several minutes, JPG sequences - several seconds, heavy EXR may stop playback in second.

After stopping the only way to restore playback is reboot Resolve. One process called GUI Thread I need to kill manually, because it loads one thread and doesn't close after exit Resolve

I recorded a [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaUgM4QgeKk)

Is it a known problem? How to solve this issue?

System details:

```
OS: Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64 
Host: X570 UD 
Kernel: 5.3.0-24-generic 
DE: GNOME 3.34.1 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3900X 12- (24) @ 3.800GHz 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 
Memory:  64331MiB 
HDD: M2 512GB
```

Comment: Can you provide a few system details: CPU, GPU, RAM and HDD or SSD.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix added to the post body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by reinstalling via [MakeResolveDeb](https://www.danieltufvesson.com/makeresolvedeb)

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to this problem of system being too slow to cope with data stream:

- [Slow and frozen playback issue update.](https://www.lwks.com/index.php?option=com_kunena&func=view&catid=23&id=62146&Itemid=81#ftop)

In answering his own question, the OP noted:

> After further investigation I've come to the conclusion that I am
>   hitting the data transfer rate ceiling for my laptop. The files I have
>   problems with real time playback are in the 90MB/sec range or higher.
>
> Files with data transfer rates below 60MB/sec work just fine.

One solution by other posters was to upgrade HDD to an SSD.

---

When the video pauses use `journalctl -b-0 -xe` to check for error messages. If you see:

```
NMI watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#12 stuck for 23s! [DOM Worker:1364]
```

Then see this tutorial: [AMD Ryzen: Problems and Fixes](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/amd-ryzen-problems-and-fixes/55533/1)

Comment: I already have M2 drive

Comment: @Crantisz I updated answer with link and to check `journalctl -b-0 -xe` for error messages. Hopefully there is a clue there.

Comment: I't not pauses, it just stops updating completely.